# ¿Es posible crear un diccionario con varios valores en una clave?

Tags: python, diccionarios

¿Es posible crear un diccionario con varios valores en una clave?

Por ejemplo:

```
dict = {k1:v1, k2:v2, k3:v4,v4,v6}
dict = {A:22, B:34, C:35,90,21}
if dict.k = 'C':
    dict[C] = dict[C].append(dict.v)
```

Aquí, la clave `k3` tendría los valores "v4", "v4" y "v6". En el segundo caso, la clave `C` tendría valores 35, 90 y 21.

(El código es un ejemplo de lo que quiero)

Answer (score 4):

A cada clave de un diccionario le puedes asociar un valor de cualquier tipo. En tu caso necesitas asociarle una lista, para poder añadir cosas. Si le asocias un entero como has hecho, después no podrás hacer `dict[C].append()`, puesto que los enteros no tienen el método `.append()`.

Por tanto lo que buscas sería así:

```
mi_dict = {"A": [22], "B": [34], "C": [35,90,21] }
mi_dict["C"].append(20)
```

**Nota** el "código" que habías puesto en la pregunta tenía muchos errores, no relacionados con lo que preguntabas. Por ejemplo:

- Usar `dict` como nombre para una variable es mala idea, pues `dict` es el tipo de datos Python, y el constructor para un diccionario.
- Un valor como `{A:22}` sería en general un error, pues la `A` debe ir entre comillas (a menos que `A` sea el nombre de otra variable cuyo valor quieras usar como clave, pero creo que no es el caso).
- La comparación `if dict.k = 'C':` no tiene sentido, De entrada `dict` no tiene un campo llamado `k`. Por otro lado una comparación se hace con `==` y no  con `=`. Finalmente ¿Qué pretendías? Si pretendías mirar si la clave "C" estaba entre las claves del diccionario, deberías haber hecho: `if "C" in dict.keys()`, o aún más simple `if "C" in dict`.
- El intento de acceder a `dict[C]` es de nuevo un error al no estar la `C` entre comillas
- La asignación a `dict["C"]` no es necesaria, pues estás usando `append()` que modifica la lista *in-situ*. De hecho, ya que `append()` no te retorna la lista modificada sino `None`, al asignar ese resultado a `dict["C"]` pierdes la lista.
- `dict.v` no es un campo válido de un diccionario ¿qué pretendías aquí?

Al margen de eso, puede interesarte conocer la existencia de [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), que permite crear diccionarios cuyos elementos sean de un tipo por defecto y se creen automáticamente si no existen. Entonces podrías hacer algo como:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mi_dict = defaultdict(list)
mi_dict["A"].append(1)
```

sin que te dé errores. La última línea intenta acceder a una clave `"A"` que no existe, pero en lugar de "romper", ya que estamos ante un `defaultdict` cuyo tipo por defecto he puesto que sea `list`, se creará en ese momento el elemento `mi_dict["A"]` como una lista vacía, por lo que puedo realizar el `.append()` y meter en ella un 1. Me ahorro así verificar si la clave ya existía antes de intentar añadir a ella.

Comment: especialmente útil `defaultdict`, muy práctico en casos así

Answer (score 0):

### El código original es el siguiente:

```
for subchild1 in element:
        if subchild1.tag == 'InfoRoute':
            for route in subchild1:
                if route.tag == 'ElemStatRoute':
                    if route.attrib['Elemname'].find('DCO') > 0:
                        DictDCO = {route.attrib['Elemname']: list(subchild1.attrib['RouteName'])}
                        print (DictDCO)
```

---

Se trata de un fichero `XML` y lo que quiero es que cuando encuentre el mismo `Elemname` me incluya todas las `RouteName` en el valor de la `Keys` del diccionario.

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o estas ampliando el contenido de tu pregunta?

Comment: Es la misma pregunta anterior. El código anterior era un ejemplo pero este es el código original y el problema es que no consigo ampliar mi list()

Comment: la zona de respuestas no es espacio para exponer dudas o preguntas, en todo caso dale editar a tu pregunta original y edita lo que consideres necesario.

Comment: @AlberM Esto no se parece en nada a la pregunta original. Te sugiero hacer una pregunta nueva para no liar, y en ella poner algo más de contexto sobre la estructura de tus datos y dónde quieres añadir elementos a listas.